# How to return the cursor to its previous position after the dot command?

Tags: vim

I used to have a macro that would return the cursor to its previous position the moment I hit the `.` (repeat command)

This was pretty useful, since I use `.` a lot.

Basically, I want `.` to do exactly what it does now -- but without changing the cursor position.

I know it's possible, but I've forgotten how to do it.

Comment: can you make some examples? it is not clear. what do you mean "but without changing the cursor position." what do you want  to repeat?

Comment: Could you not just set a mark before hitting `.`? You could look at some of the other marks like `\`.` or `\`^`.

Comment: You could… find it again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is to use marks: `` nnoremap . ma.`a ``

What this does:

- marks a position with `ma`
- repeats the last change with `.`
- returns to the marked position with `` `a ``.

It will overwrite whatever position was previously marked with `a`, but you can replace `a` with whatever letter you want.